# Getting full "monday to sunday" weeks between two dates

Tags: java

Let's see if you can help me. I want to get the number of weeks (starting on monday and finishing on sunday) between two dates, d1 and d2. Let's suppose that d2 is earlier of d1. That part of the code is already programmed and working. My problem now is that I'm not being able to code correctly the week program. This is what I made for now:

```
public static void getFullWeeks(Calendar d1, Calendar d2){
    int Weeks = 0;
    Calendar date2 = d2;
    Calendar addWeek = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    addWeek.setTime(date2.getTime());
    addWeek.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);

    while(addWeek.before(d1) || addWeek.equals(d1)){
        if(date2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.MONDAY){
            Weeks++;
        }
        date2.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
    }

    System.out.println(
        "The number of weeks (from monday to sunday) between both dates are: " 
        + Weeks);
}
```

But the output is "0 weeks", so the program is not working. What's wrong? I'm not encountering the error and I'm not being capable to find a working solution for this problem.

Thank you!!

Comment: We need to know what is suma7.

Comment: Use [joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Sorry, code was in spanish and I translated it to english forgetting about that. It's fixed now.

Comment: @hd1 Joda is really confortable for working with time and dates, but I'm not allowed to use external libraries in this job

Comment: Not allowed? Quit the job, mate, that is incomprehensible

Comment: @hd1 haha sorry, I wanted to say that I can't use external libraries in this particular project (My english is quite bad). I'm not doing it for a job, I'm actually studying Java, and for these first exercises the professor does not allow us to use external APIs as Joda.

Comment: Ahh... you do know SO doesn't like homework questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java 8 without external libraries you can do something like the following:

*Edited to account for week starting on Monday

```
// TechTrip - ASSUMPTION d1 is earlier than d2
// leave that for exercise
public static long getFullWeeks(Calendar d1, Calendar d2){
    // In Java the week starts on Sunday from an integral perspective
    //  public final static int SUNDAY = 1;
    // SEQUENTIAL UP TO
    // public final static int SATURDAY = 7;

    // make the starting date relative to the Monday we need to calculate from
    int dayOfStartWeek = d1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    // IF we have a partial week we should add an offset that moves the start
    // date UP TO the next Monday to simulate a week starting on Monday
    // eliminating partial weeks from the calculation
    // NOTE THIS METHOD WILL RETURN NEGATIVES IF D1 < D2 after adjusting for 
    // offset
    if (dayOfStartWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
        // add an offset of 1 day because this is a partial week
        d1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
    } else if (dayOfStartWeek != Calendar.MONDAY){
        // add an offset for the partial week
        // Hence subtract from 9 accounting for shift by 1
        // and start at 1
        // ex if WEDNESDAY we need to add 9-4 (WED Int Val) = 5 days
        d1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 9 - dayOfStartWeek);
    }

    Instant d1i = Instant.ofEpochMilli(d1.getTimeInMillis());
    Instant d2i = Instant.ofEpochMilli(d2.getTimeInMillis());

    LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(d1i, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(d2i, ZoneId.systemDefault());

    return ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between(startDate, endDate);
}
```

Here's the main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar d1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar d2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    d2.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 6);
    System.out.println(
            "The number of weeks (from monday to sunday) between both dates are: " 
            + getFullWeeks(d1, d2));
}
```

The output is as follows if the start date is a MONDAY:

The number of weeks (from monday to sunday) between both dates are: 6

Note, I did not assign date d2 to d1, making it the same reference. In that case you would get 0.

*The ChronoUnit takes a Temporal which is simply a date, time or offset. They must be of the same type. Temporals can be manipulated with plus and minus.

Comment: When looking at ChronoUnit it is important to understand that the calculations are relative to the start date in absolute terms. The calculation returns a whole number, representing the number of complete units between the two temporals. For example, the amount in hours between the times 11:30 and 13:29 will only be one hour as it is one minute short of two hours

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me there are couple of little mistakes you made:

1.) Your output is 0 weeks because elsewhere in your code you must have called this method with your first argument, `d1`, earlier than the second, while in the method body, you assume that `d2` is earlier than `d1`. Such mistakes are easily avoided by using meaningful argument names. Appropriate argument names in this case are for example `start` and `end`.

2) If you execute this method using arguments in which `d2` is earlier than `d1`, your method would fall into an infinite loop. It looks to me that adding to `date2` does not change the date in `addWeek`.

3) Your method counts the number of weeks from Tuesday to Monday instead of Monday to Sunday. To fix this, add seven days to `addWeek` instead of six, or change the while loop to check only if `addWeek` is before `d1` and increment `weeks` on sunday.

Putting all this together, I believe this will give you what you're looking for:

```
public static void getFullWeeks(Calendar start, Calendar end)
{
    System.out.println("The number of weeks (from monday to sunday) between both dates are: " + getNrWeeksBetween(start, end));
}

private static int getNrWeeksBetween(Calendar start, Calendar end)
{
    int weeks = 0;

    Calendar counter = new GregorianCalendar();
    counter.setTime( start.getTime() );
    counter.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);

    while( counter.before(end) )
    {
        if(counter.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) weeks++;
        counter.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    return weeks;
}
```

Comment: simple, but works

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm's wrong; your `while` loop needs to compare the same Calendar object you're modifying, but you don't do that, so you either have an infinite loop or you exit immediately with a return value of 0, depending on whether addDate is before or after d1 (since neither one changes).  Your code should be:

```
public static void getFullWeeks(Calendar d1, Calendar d2){
    int Weeks = 0;
    Calendar addWeek = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    addWeek.setTime(d2.getTime());
    addWeek.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);

    while(addWeek.before(d1) || addWeek.equals(d1)){
        if(addWeek.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.MONDAY){
            Weeks++;
        }
        addWeek.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
    }

    System.out.println(
        "The number of weeks (from monday to sunday) between both dates are: " 
        + Weeks);
}
```

Comment: I almost deleted my answer once I realized this was a homework problem.  I'm going to leave it, but I'm also going to give the answer I nearly replaced it with: the problem is **VERY OBVIOUS** when you step through it with a debugger.  So this should be your first lesson as a Java student: learn how to set a breakpoint on a line and then run with a debugger to stop at that line, step line-by-line through your method, examine variables, etc.  The debugger will save you **hours** of guesswork about what's going wrong with your problems; it should always be your first step with any problem.